# Set default face color to interp

Tags: matlab, default

When using Matlab for plotting 3d surfaces, on almost all occasions I find the 'interp' face color much better looking. I therefore would like to make it my standard option. However, I am can't seem to find the line of code that can do that for me.
I am searching for something like: set(0,'DefaultFigureColormap',gray(64)), but rather than change the figure colormap, I'd like to change the face color to interp.

Comment: I dont think you can, but it would be nice to known

Comment: I found out how to do it. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

add the following to `startup.m`:

```
set(0,'defaultsurfacefacecolor','interp')
```